# Price item reordering behaving erratically

Tags: price-sets

Today while adding price items to an existing price set, I find that neither clicking the the reorder arrows nor updating the order text field is saving the item order properly.  When you try to reorder an item using the arrows, it either moves to the wrong place or does not move it at all.  If you try to change it using the order text field, it does not save or randomly displaces the item that already used that number, instead of shifting it down one.  I was able after many attempts to get the correct order by clicking the bottom arrow for each misplaced item, and then moving it up from there.

We are using CiviCRM 5.33.5 on Drupal 7.8.1.  A recent change that may be relevant was an upgrade this month of PHP to 7.3.29 from 7.2.18.  Any ideas on what is causing this behavior?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the db? if so you may want to look in the table. you may find lots of price items with the same weight. altering in the db should be safe and may fix the issue for you.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks.  I found 3 items with a weight of 4.  It took several rounds of updating rows manually to fix them all, as other rows would increment with my changes.

Comment: great. have added as Answer, pls +1 and Accept it so it is useful to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the db then you may want to look in the table. you may find lots of price items with the same weight. altering in the db should be safe and may fix the issue for you

if you do not have access to the db then you may find that you can sort out the problem of multiple items having the same weight value though it may take several rounds of jiggling.